# How to filter flights by arrival time?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, tickets

I've tried everything from Kayak to Skyscanner, but I can't seem to find out if it is possible to sort the results of a flight search by arrival time at the destination. Of course I know there may be delays, but I'd like at least to be able to sort by estimated arrival time.

How can I filter flights from a search by arrival time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On kayak.com, once you've searched for a flight, look down the left hand side of the search results.  There's a 'take off time" for your flight, and just below that, a link for "Show landing times".

Click that, and now you can filter your flights by arrival times.

Comment: A lot of other websites offer this feature: momondo, expedia, skyscanner ... For all, you should also first search and then sort the flights (on all these websites, on the left panel, there is a bar to restrict the arrival time window).

Answer (score 3):

Try [Hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com/) I like the way they visualize the search results. You not only get an indication of the arrival time, but also the time you might spent on a transfer airport.

Answer (score 2):

Using ITA Matrix Software you can select when you want to arrive in your destination. On the row "Outbound date", "Departure" is selected by default. Click on the drop down menu and select "Arrival".

However, one cannot book through ITA Software. After finding a flight you wish to book, you must go to the listed airline's site or you can try to find the same one through some other website such as Skyscanner or Kayak.